# PEAR2\Net\Transmitter\SocketException: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect (Connection refused) by mikrotik

Tags: php, mikrotik

When i tried to connect mikrotik, it work in local but server it refused connection.

Below i gave my code

```
try {
    $client = new RouterOS\Client('192.168.1.1','test','test','8728'); 
    echo 'OK'; 
 } catch (Exception $e) { 
    die($e); 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

After so much tried cannot solved. At last found that may be it is server firewall issue. Then alternative found a solution.

1. Change mikrotik ip/services api port 8728 to 2703 or 2089.

> 2. try {
>      $client = new RouterOS\Client('192.168.1.1','test','test','2703'); 
>      echo 'OK';   } catch (Exception $e) { 
>      die($e);   }

Finally, it's working